# Over riding JavaScript defined properties using media queries

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I set the height and width of a DIV by calculating window.height and window.width properties and then assigning the values to the DIV. Now the DIV fits the entire browser viewport.

I now want to over-ride these dimensions using media queries when a user resizes the window. On a smaller screen, I want to set the height and width of the DIV to a smaller dimension than the window height and width?

Is this possible? Can heights and widths set using JavaScript be over-ridden by media queries?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "media queries"?

Comment: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Comment: What ever you assign directly to DIV via JavaScript or inline style won't be overridden by external CSS or in your case Media Queries. I recommend you to put your logic in CSS with absolute positioning with media queries or just do it all in JS. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you keep your media queries pretty simple you could do a simple javascript if/else statement.

```
 if (screen.width < 480) {
     // Set some variables
 } else {
     // Set other variables
 }
```

Another option, there's the newer [`window.matchMedia` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.matchMedia).